# Sharepoint Groups [No Access]

Tags: permissions, user, access, site-settings

I'm trying to select groups I created in Sharepoint Designer (2010). 
But they all say,

> [No Access]

when I'm using the "Grant Permissions" Screen.

If I add them in the regular sharepoint screen it works fine **Site Settings>Create Group** 

But adding in Sharepoint Designer something is wrong why? 
And Why are some groups associated with sites and others are not? 
How would I associate a global security group with a site?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so this may seem totally obvious.

If I type in the group name in the first prompt and give it a permission level then it works. 
Then once the group has a default permissions level I can then add users to it. 
It's just confusing/deceiving when it says "Grant **users** permission directly".
When you can actually grant "GROUPS" permission directly.

So Again:

1. Add the user group in Sharepoin Designer: 
   [image]
2. Goto the appropriate Sharepoint site. 
    Enter the "GROUP" name in the first Prompt in Sharepoint like so:
3. Select a Permission Level for the group. 
   [image]
4. Once a Group has access to the site its then associated. 
   Users can then be added to it.
5. Now I can add users (blurred out) into the Group.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

In SPD, after you create the group, you need to click the hyperlink for Site Permissions to assign permission levels to the group.

Comment: My bad I don't think I clearly explained this question. Thanks for you help though PiracteEric.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, I realized: In my case, I wanted to grant access on a list, for which no groups have access rights (only singe users, directly given). That's why, every group has "no access" next to the group name.